# What have I done wrong?

Tags: html, css, razor

Here is my coding.

```
<fieldset style="background-color: #719BC1; float: left; text-align: left; color: black;font-size: 14px; border-color: #719BC1; border-style: solid; height: 79px; width: 464px;">
    <li id="Transactionss" style="display: none">@Html.RadioButton("option1", "Transaction", false, new { id = "Transactions", @class = "optalign" })Transactions </li>
    <li id="Vintage_Reportss" style="display: none">@Html.RadioButton("option1", "Vintage_Report", false, new { id = "Vintage_Reports", @class = "optalign" })Vintage Report </li>
</fieldset>
```

I don't know what error I have committed here.

The Transactions Radio `button` is showing but not the Vintage Report one.

Please help me on this matter, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the `display: none;` on the Vintage `ID` and the Transactions `ID`..  Also, remove the `ul` you've left out there in the code, I'm surprised too that any of your buttons is showing up.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you have a superfluous `</ul>`

I'm surprised any radio button shows up since you have `display: none`